# What type of CCD system is required to take photos of luciferase

Tags: lab-techniques, bioluminescence

I'm working with luciferase and I want to be able to take a photo of it. The trouble is, I can see the luciferase glowing in all of its glory in front of me but no matter how hard I try, I can't take a photo of the luciferase with my DSLR (Nikon D80).

I'm curious if I'm missing a certain lens or if I should be shooting using a different lighting setup. I'm already exposing for 30". Perhaps longer?

Comment: You might want to look at [photography.se](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) too

Comment: That I have done http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20976/8852

Comment: Seem to have got some quite thorough answers there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll also want to make sure that you are imaging in complete darkness because you may have very low photon emission from your luciferase system and any amount of background light can overwhelm your signal with noise.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for a [bioluminescence imaging device](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=004738989115247203233:09r2ltc-nlc&ie=UTF-8&q=luciferase#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=bioluminescence%20imaging). These have very sensitive CCD camera and exposure times are around 5 minutes in complete darkness.

Comment: here's an example: http://www.berthold.com/ww/en/pub/bioanalytik/produkte/lb981.cfm